# Call function when click on a link

Tags: ios, uiwebview

In my iPhone application, i use web view to display formatted text like this :

```
Tél :
0442059840
```

The number `0442059840` is a link : `<a href="">0442059840</a>`.
In my case, i want to make a telephone call when i click on that link, is that possible? Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the `href` parameter point to the phone number:

```
<a href="tel://0442059840">0442059840</a>
```

You can also let the web view parse for links by setting the data detector types. In that case you just need the phone number, and not the `<a></a>` tag.

Comment: Hi mortenfast, i did exactly like you explain,but, when i click, nothing is happened, is that because i test the app on the simulator?

Comment: It probably is. If you test it on a device, it will offer to place a call.